# Extra Argument in call when creating and calling a class initialiser and passing in the literal values Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift, variables

I have a small problem in swift. Let's say I have a class called Pet. 
Pet has a variable for name and noise, created like so:

```
class Pet
{
    var name : String = ""
    var canMakeNoise : Bool = true
}
```

Now, when I call initialise the class creating let's say a cat, I can easily do it like so:

```
var cat: Pet()
cat.name = "Garfield"
cat.canMakeNoise = false
```

This works smoothly, however when trying to pass it in directly using literal values like so:

```
let cat : Pet("Garfield",true)
```

or

```
let cat : Pet(name:"Garfield",canMakeNoise:true)
```

I get this error:

> Swift Compile Error - Extra Argument in call

Why is that? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add arguments to the initializer than you need to specify a new init function instead of relying on the default one.  Here's how you'd do it in your case:

```
class Pet {
    var name : String = ""  
    var canMakeNoise : Bool = true

    init( name : String, canMakeNoise : Bool ) {
       self.name = name
       self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise
    }
}

var kitty = Pet(name: "Cat", canMakeNoise: true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Since you use default values for your variables, xCode does not find a need for initializer. So when you create a new instance of the class it will be a `Pet` with `name = ””` and `canMakeNoice = true`.
If you want to change these default values you will need to supply a init method (and you can than remove these default values)

```
class Pet{
    var name:String
    var canMakeNoise:Bool

    init(name:String, canMakeNoise:Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise
    }

    convenience init (name:String){
        self.name = name
        self.init(name:name, canMakeNoise: true)
    }
}
```

I’ve supplied two init methods here. The first one takes 2 arguments:

```
var cat: Pet = Pet(name: "Kitten", canMakeNoise: true)
```

This will create a `Pet` with the supplied name and the supplied `canMakeNoise`.
If you want to you can also supply a `convenience init` This is a shortened init. In this case used to be able to make another instance of the `Pet` class.

```
var dog: Pet = Pet(name: "Doggy")
```

As you see we don’t supply the `canMakeNoise` property here cause the convenience initializer does that for us (and uses `true` as the `canMakeNoice`)

Comment: By providing a default param to the init methods `canMakeNoise` you event can avoid the convinience init method 

```swift
    class Pet{
        var name:String
        var canMakeNoise:Bool
        
        init(name:String, canMakeNoise:Bool = true){
            self.name = name
            self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise
        }
    }

    Pet(name: "Hog")
    Pet(name: "Butterfly", canMakeNoise: false)
```